# finding a git branch path

Tags: git, terminal

I'm trying to send someone a clone link for a git repository.

so this will give me access to cloning the master. But I want to give out a branch clone path how would I go about finding that path using terminal. The branch is a remote branch.

```
git@git.blobkick.com:mainproject.git
```

Comment: That link should be enough with a branch name. Link give access to clone any branch, `master` one is use to be default often.

Comment: There's no "clone link" or "branch path", you should find out about the command used to clone directly to a specified branch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "branch clone path", but maybe this will help...

When you a clone a remote repository, you get all the branches.  You typically end up on the `master` branch, after which you can select your branch using the `checkout` command:

```
$ git clone git@git.blobkick.com:mainproject.git
$ cd mainproject
$ git checkout mybranch
```

If you want to end up on a branch other than `master` as part of the `clone` operation, you can use the `-b` (`--branch`) option:

```
$ git clone -b mybranch git@git.blobkick.com:mainproject.git
```

This would switch the local repository to the `mybranch` branch after completing the clone operation.  This is identical to the above sequence of commands (well, other than the `cd` command).

If this doesn't address your question, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Just look for remote branches

```
git branch -r
```

After that give clone it via

```
git clone git@git.blobkick.com:mainproject.git -b remote_branchh
```